# What was an 80s TV series about family in future on the run

Tags: story-identification, tv

There was a short lived series in the 80s about a family that is traveling together in the future dystopian society. I can only remember one scene and it has bugged me for years. The scene is one in which the teenage son joins the villain army as a ruse. When his loyalty is tested (by being asked to place his hand in a flame) he passed. The flame turned out to be cold.

Comment: What language was it in? Can you remember anything about the family members? Hoe many, how old were they etc. What were they on the run for?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/140142/identification-of-mid-80s-time-travel-tv-show (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 6):

You're remembering the episode "The Zone Troopers Build Men" from the 1985 show [Otherworld](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otherworld_(TV_series)), about a family lost on a parallel Earth that has a mix of different types of societies in different "zones", including some with futuristic technology. The scene in question can be seen starting at around 18:30 in the video below:

Comment: check out Sarek! (Mark Lenard)