# Identification of mid-80s time travel tv show

Tags: story-identification, tv

Hey guys I've been trying to find the name of this show for years and it's bothering me. It was definitely mid-80s (probably about '85-'87). It was about a family who somehow travelled forward through time. They were "on the run" from some evil guy dressed in all black who drove this black futuristic vehicle.

I'm sure it was an entire family who was sort of "lost" in this future world as this guy in black pursued them. It had several character actors from the 80s (I can see their faces but can't place them), especially the evil guy and the father character who I know I've seen in other things from that era.

I know also that it didn't last long, maybe only a few episodes. Maybe only one episode? But it was when the VCR first came out and I watched this one episode over and over.

Thanks.

- Entire family travelled forward in time somehow, get "lost" and end up on the run from some security guard type evil guy in all black
- Mid 1980s - probably 85-87
- Television, USA, English
- Very short-lived
- Caucasian family, they were always altogether, it was clear they were a family "lost" in the future
- I only saw the first episode, unsure if there were any more
- They somehow travelled into the future, clearly accidentally, they didn't intentionally travel through time (I don't remember how they did it) and the security in the future was after them and they were running around, exploring this future world
- Main character was just the family, but also they focused on the evil guy in black a lot. The evil guy was a 80s character actor I know I've seen in other things.

Comment: It would help if you could work your way through the checklists [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question).

Comment: Can you describe the family (caucasian/other)? What makes you think they were a family? Who was the *main* character? What made you think that the world was futuristic? How did they travel through time? Was the baddie contemporaneous or did he follow them through time? Did they time-travel more than once?

Comment: @starpilotsix Thank you! That's it. I didn't realize it wasn't really "the future" .. put as answer and I'll accept it thanks

Comment: FYI - My family had a VCR in the late 70's. They didn't "first come out" in the mid-80's.

Comment: OK I meant when my family first got one

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe you are refering to [Otherworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otherworld_(TV_series)) which lasted only for 8 episodes in 1985.

The family are on vacation in Eqypt and get sucked through a portal in the pyramid. They didn't actually go to the future, but another *earthlike* planet.

The villain was [Jonathan Banks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Banks) who is currently on Better Call Saul.

Comment: And let's not forget my favourite Martian, Ray Walston!

Comment: Wow, I have never heard of this movie in my life. Most movies sucked in the 80s, that poor Jonathan Banks, did sucky movies until Better Call Saul, that's life I guess. I am still trying to show the world my best in my field and I am not getting any younger either.