# TV Series about explorer of strange places

Tags: story-identification, tv

When I was much younger than now, probably in the '90s, I remember a TV series about travellers around strange places.
I remember two episodes.

In one there were androids that were living like humans. They eat as well, but the shops sell only "meat", without specifying what kind of meat, and "good food", in cans.
I remember that at a certain point they had to be subject to an "analysis".

In another episode, there were savage people drinking gypsum with narcotic properties.

Do any of you remember such a TV series at all? Did I dream everything?

Country of airing: Italy. The channel was probably one of Rai.

The producer country seemed UK, possibly Germany. Surely not Italy.

Comment: Can you tell us what country you were in, and what network you saw it on? Every detail is valuable.

Comment: Thanks @ClaraDiazSanchez I added this information in the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This may have been [Otherworld](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088587/), an American TV series from 1985.  It lasted only eight episodes.

In the pilot episode there are androids that look human and live human-like lives.  The military police can perform "memory audits" on the androids at will.

In another episode there's a bit where the local supermarket sells "meat" in grey cans.

Episode summaries are [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otherworld_(TV_series)).

The entire series is on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLzovi87vDfzIHuqJB6VRYnRC9BoHwCeXs).

Comment: If so, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/140142/identification-of-mid-80s-time-travel-tv-show

Comment: Thanks a lot that's it! The opening theme is definitely familiar to my mind. The first episode is the one referring to the androids, while the 5th is the one referring to drinking gypsum (not sure about the translation though). I even found the series in Italian on dailymotion. Great!