# Sci-fi TV episode from the 80s or 90s where a family has to answer questions about baseball to prove where they're from

Tags: story-identification, tv

I'm trying to find a TV episode where a family traveled to another dimension and in order to get home they have to answer questions about baseball among other questions that anyone from the U.S. would know. Everyone else from the other dimension has been unable to answer the questions because they don't have baseball in their world. I thought it might be from the Twilight Zone reboot but I can't find this episode.

Comment: To be clear, when you say "another dimension," do you mean an alternate Earth?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 8):

[Otherworld](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088587/), S01E08 "[Princess Metra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HLnyIxKgHME&list=PLzovi87vDfzIHuqJB6VRYnRC9BoHwCeXs&index=8)", 1985?

This is the final episode of the show.  The baseball quiz question can be found around the 9 minute mark.

The entire series is on YouTube.

Comment: If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/140142/identification-of-mid-80s-time-travel-tv-show?noredirect=1&lq=1